# getting image, why does const name matter?

Tags: javascript

```
const notifs = document.createElement('notifs');
notifs.src = 'notifs.svg'; 
notifs.innerText = "Notifs";
notifs.onclick = function(){YourWorriesLink()};
bottomBox.appendChild(notifs);
```

Why isn't this working?

```
//HOME ICON
const img = document.createElement('img'); 
img.src = 'notifs.svg'; 
img.onclick = function(){home()};
topBox.appendChild(img);
```

When this works?
What exactly is it that makes the difference?

And how do you then apply multiple images to a site? I can't call them all img I'm assuming.

Comment: Maybe becos the <notifs> element does not exist maybe you mean `const notifs = document..createElement('img') ?`

Comment: Side Note: I would also encourate you to use the `addEventListener` method, rather than the inline attribute, from a general coding practices standpoint.

Comment: Like @Selim mentioned the top code is going to create a <notifs> element, which isn't valid HTML.  Though, you'll get mixed results based on your web browser.  Are you getting any console errors?

Answer (score 1):

notifs is not an HTML element tag - it is the name of the const you want to create. Once you have created the img element you can refer to it as notif in the way you are doing.

```
const notifs = document.createElement('img');
notifs.src = 'notifs.svg'; 
notifs.innerText = "Notifs";
notifs.onclick = function(){YourWorriesLink()};
bottomBox.appendChild(notifs);
```

Minor note: Safari IOS at least has problems showing some types of svg files if they are presented as src in an img element. Using svg elements seems to work more generally.

Comment: Now I get it. So you have to create elements with specific element tags, to get the property.

Comment: Yup,you create an element with a tag (img, div, a, span etc) and that gives you an element and you can have as many variables (like notif in your example) 'pointing' at it as you like, and called (more or less) what you like.